# Unix command to remove before specific field by length before a String

Tags: unix, sed

How to remove a fixed length field before a string.

Example

Input:

```
"abcdefg": {"field_string","xxx","yyy"}, "hijklmn": {"field_string","xyz","dey"}, "opqrstu": {field_string","xxx","yyy"}
```

Output:

```
{"field_string","xxx","yyy"}, {"field_string","xyz","dey"}, {field_string","xxx","yyy"}
```

before `'{"field_string'` character length has to removed

The Input is repeated on every line

Thank you

Comment: A double quote in front of `field_string` just after `"opqrstu"` seems missing including the expected output. Is this a typo or intended one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way:

```
sed -e 's/.\{11\}\({[^}]*}\)/\1/g'
```

Since you said `fixed length`, so this just remove 11 characters before every `{}` block.

Or a more accurate way (remove `"...":` before `{}` block):

```
sed -e 's/"[^"]*": \({[^}]*}\)/\1/g'
```

Note above ones didn't check `file_string` exists or not, if you want to, and not sure the first `"` exists or not, use this:

```
sed -e 's/"[^"]*": \({"\{0,1\}field_string[^}]*}\)/\1/g'
```

Or strictly with your description:

```
sed -e 's/"[^"]*": \({"\{0,1\}field_string\)/\1/g'
```

Eg:

```
$ cat file
"abcdefg": {"field_string","xxx","yyy"}, "hijklmn": {"field_string","xyz","dey"}, "opqrstu": {field_string","xxx","yyy"}

$ sed -e 's/"[^"]*": \({"\{0,1\}field_string\)/\1/g' file
{"field_string","xxx","yyy"}, {"field_string","xyz","dey"}, {field_string","xxx","yyy"}
```